# Docker: supervisord doesn't start uwsgi

Tags: python, docker, uwsgi, supervisord

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.2
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install supervisor python build-essential python-dev python-pip python-setuptools -y
RUN apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libpq-dev postgresql-common postgresql-client -y
RUN apt-get install openssl openssl-blacklist openssl-blacklist-extra -y
RUN apt-get install nginx -y
RUN pip install "pip>=7.0"
RUN pip install virtualenv uwsgi

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
ADD configs/new-canon/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
ADD canonicaliser_api /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api
ADD config_local.py /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/config/config_local.py
RUN virtualenv /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv
RUN source /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/requirements.txt
RUN export CFLAGS=-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include/
RUN source /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv/bin/activate && cd /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/ && python setup.py build_ext --inplace
RUN cp /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/*.so /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions
RUN rm -rf /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/canonicaliser
RUN rm -r /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/build

RUN mkdir /var/run/flask-uwsgi
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/run/flask-uwsgi
# RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api
RUN mkdir /var/log/flask-uwsgi
RUN touch /var/log/flask-uwsgi/dqs_canon.log
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/flask-uwsgi
RUN mkdir /etc/flask-uwsgi

ADD configs/new-canon/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.conf /etc/init/
ADD configs/new-canon/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/

RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 8888
#CMD uwsgi --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

**supervisord:**

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:flask-uwsgi]
command=/bin/bash -c "exec uwsgi --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini -DFOREGROUND"
```

**flask-uwsgi.ini:**

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api
socket = /var/run/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.sock
home = /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv
wsgi-file = /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/flask_uwsgi.py
callable = app
master = true
; www-data uid/gid
uid = 33
gid = 33
http-socket = :8888
die-on-term = true
processes = 4
threads = 2
logger = file:/var/log/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.log
```

**Error message:**

```
bash-3.2$ docker run -p 8888:8888 canon
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:295: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2015-08-06 11:27:42,590 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2015-08-06 11:27:42,591 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
2015-08-06 11:27:42,625 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2015-08-06 11:27:42,625 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2015-08-06 11:27:42,625 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2015-08-06 11:27:43,629 INFO spawned: 'flask-uwsgi' with pid 7
2015-08-06 11:27:43,666 INFO exited: flask-uwsgi (exit status 1; not expected)
2015-08-06 11:27:44,671 INFO spawned: 'flask-uwsgi' with pid 8
2015-08-06 11:27:44,678 INFO exited: flask-uwsgi (exit status 1; not expected)
2015-08-06 11:27:46,687 INFO spawned: 'flask-uwsgi' with pid 9
2015-08-06 11:27:46,694 INFO exited: flask-uwsgi (exit status 1; not expected)
2015-08-06 11:27:49,707 INFO spawned: 'flask-uwsgi' with pid 10
2015-08-06 11:27:49,713 INFO exited: flask-uwsgi (exit status 1; not expected)
2015-08-06 11:27:50,715 INFO gave up: flask-uwsgi entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

if I run this like instead, it works fine. So It can't be bad uwsgi settings:

```
CMD uwsgi --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini
```

Comment: Is `flask-uwsgi` generating any errors on stdout/stderr (does supervisor collect and log this somewhere)? Does anything show up in the `flask-uwsgi.log` file? Why are you setting command to `bash -c "..."` rather than just `command= uwsgi --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini -DFOREGROUND`?

Comment: Does it work if you take out `exec` from the supervisord config? You shouldn't be calling that in this case.

Comment: @larsks I did so as you recommended. No change in erro output.  There is also no `/var/log/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.log`.  Strange as it seems it doesnt even get that far.

Comment: Is your image available somewhere we can pull it?

Comment: @AdrianMouat Yes it looks now like this: `command=uwsgi --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini -DFOREGROUND` .  But doesnt work

Comment: @larsks Unfortunately the code inside the image is company's proprietary and I'm not allowed to share it.  It seems `/var/run/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.sock` doesn't exist either.  `/var/run/flask-uwsgi/` is owned by www-data, but `supervisor.sock` is running as root. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Looking at the docker article, I understand why you used bash and exec. https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Comment: I think you'll need to give the full path to uwsgi i.e. `/usr/bin/uwsgi` or whatever it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just that you need to provide the full path and get rid of `-DFOREGROUND` (which isn't a uwsgi flag). Try:

```
command=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is still the same problem.  :(

Comment: What's in the supervisord.log? You should be able to find it with `docker diff`

Comment: Ha! good one. In the supervisord.log is the same as pasted above. (screen output). However in the same folder are other log files. One sayes `[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi: invalid option -- 'D'`

Comment: YEEESS I found it: `command=/bin/bash -c "exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini" -DFOREGROUND`   Feel free to correct and I accept your answer.

Comment: Yeah I think -DFOREGROUND is an apache flag; you should be able to delete it

Comment: I still don't think you need the exec. Try with my updated answer (no -DFOREGROUND)